# Merging two files on columns with different lengths with AWK

Tags: arrays, awk, merge

I am trying to merge two files on column 1 in test1 and test2.

```
test1
::::::::::::::
My Mynose mynose rest
hello
baby two
four
::::::::::::::
test2
::::::::::::::
My  1
hello   2
two 3
```

The first column in test1 is a string and each word should match the exact word i the column 1 of test2.

The desired output should be:

```
My Mynose mynose rest 1
hello 2
baby two 3
four N/A
```

I've tried variations of:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++; next} n=split($5,x," " );for (i=;i<=n;i++); {if(x[i] in a) print $0,a}' test2 test1
```

But cannot seem to get the correct answer.

Could someone help.
Thanks

Comment: the input files are: test1:                                                                               My Mynose mynose rest
hello
baby two
four

Comment: How are you defining a "column" in file test1? The output should include `baby two N/A` because "baby" is not in test2.

Answer (score 0):

`awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next}  { { found=0; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if($i in a) { print $0,a[$i]; found=1; break; } } if (!found) { print $0,"N/A"} }' test2 test1`

Code in detail:

`NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next}` for the first file make an array of first field (word) with the second field as value

Next open a new block (which will be used on each line on second file only (due to the next in the first block)

`found=0;` setting a var to print N/A is not found

`for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {` looping over the fields (each word) NF is the number of fields space being the default separator

`if($i in a) { print $0,a[$i]; found=1; break; }` for each word, if it's ($i will become $1, $2, etc.) in the array, print the line and the corresponding value, set the var to know we found and stop looping (to avoid multiples entries if more than one word match).

`if (!found) { print $0,"N/A"}` if previous loop did not find a word of this line, print the line and N/A